# Move questions from [viper] and remove the tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

[viper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viper) has a clear description of what replacement tag should be used in which case:

> Please consider using the tags [viper-architecture], [viper-go], [viper-mode], or [viper-lang] instead of catch-all [viper]. (1) [viper-architecture] VIPER is an architectural application design pattern: {View, Interactor, Presenter, Entity, Router}. (2) [viper-mode] Viper is a Vi emulation package for Emacs. (3) [viper-go] is a configuration library for Golang. (4) [viper-lang] is for formal, separation-logic-based verifiers of programming languages.

There aren't many left, and most of them have one of [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), indicating that they should be moved under [viper-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viper-architecture).